# How to send a message successfully using the new Gmail REST API?

Tags: rest, gmail, gmail-api

**I'm currently trying to test the new [Gmail REST API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)**.

In the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it) it is possible to authorize requests using OAuth 2.0 and to execute a request, i.e. send a message.

First I authorized.
[image]

I'm using the following **test data** (and of course I used a valid `to` email address):

```
{    
   "raw": "c2VuZGluZyBhIG1haWwgdXNpbmcgR21haWwgUkVTVCBBUEk=",  
   "payload": { 
     "headers": [ 
       { "name": "to",      "value": "info@something.com"   }, 
       { "name": "from",    "value": "taifunbaer@gmail.com" }, 
       { "name": "subject", "value": "Test Gmail REST API"  } 
     ],
     "mimeType": "text/plain" 
   }
}
```

I also get a `200 OK` and the following **result** back, which looks fine.

```
{
  "id": "146dee391881b35b",
  "threadId": "146dee391881b35b",
}
```

However, the mail will not be sent successfully and I can find an message from `nobody@gmail.com` in the inbox instead;: `"An error occurred, your message has not been sent."`

[image]

Questions:
**1. Did someone test this successfully?

2. Do I have to add some other parameter to get this running?**

**EDIT**: There are 2 different HTTP request methods,

1. the Upload URI for media upload requests, and
2. the Metadata URI for metadata-only requests

`The API Explorer currently supports metadata requests only`, which means plain-text messages without attachment, and this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: sure, of course I authorized the request first, else I guess I would not get a `200 OK` back...

Comment: @Taifun, How did you created the RFC 2822 string, Is there any libraries or hard coded it, any examples?

Comment: @Sasikanth This depends on your favorite programming language. [see my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24461102/1545993) how to web-safe base64 encode the complete message

Answer (score 64, accepted):

got it!

after reading the [RFC 2822 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#appendix-A) I found out, that the complete message needs to be passed in the `raw` parameter, see the example:

```
From: John Doe <jdoe@machine.example> 
To: Mary Smith <mary@example.net> 
Subject: Saying Hello 
Date: Fri, 21 Nov 1997 09:55:06 -0600 
Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>

This is a message just to say hello. So, "Hello".
```

So after base64 encoding the complete message, passing it in the `raw` parameter without using any other parameter, it works fine.

**Edit 1:**
As @Amit mentioned, it must be **web-safe base64** encoded, see also https://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/wiki/WebSafeBase64

> So to convert the base64 alpha into a format that is "web-safe" the
> following changes are recommended:
>
> ```
> + --> - (char 62, plus to dash)
> / --> _ (char 63, slash to underscore)
> = --> * padding
> ```

To only convert `+` to `-` and `/`to `_` was sufficient for me.

**Edit 2:**
To answer the question of @Hjulle here an example: you only need the `userId` and in the request body the `raw` parameter. Let's assume, your email address is `jdoe@machine.example`

First Base64 encode the complete message (see above) using an [online encoder](http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html) and you get this string:

```
RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPGpkb2VAbWFjaGluZS5leGFtcGxlPiAKVG86IE1hcnkgU21pdGggPG1h
cnlAZXhhbXBsZS5uZXQ+IApTdWJqZWN0OiBTYXlpbmcgSGVsbG8gCkRhdGU6IEZyaSwgMjEgTm92
IDE5OTcgMDk6NTU6MDYgLTA2MDAgCk1lc3NhZ2UtSUQ6IDwxMjM0QGxvY2FsLm1hY2hpbmUuZXhh
bXBsZT4KClRoaXMgaXMgYSBtZXNzYWdlIGp1c3QgdG8gc2F5IGhlbGxvLiBTbywgIkhlbGxvIi4=
```

Now convert  `+` to `-` and `/`to `_` and you get

```
RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPGpkb2VAbWFjaGluZS5leGFtcGxlPiAKVG86IE1hcnkgU21pdGggPG1h
cnlAZXhhbXBsZS5uZXQ-IApTdWJqZWN0OiBTYXlpbmcgSGVsbG8gCkRhdGU6IEZyaSwgMjEgTm92
IDE5OTcgMDk6NTU6MDYgLTA2MDAgCk1lc3NhZ2UtSUQ6IDwxMjM0QGxvY2FsLm1hY2hpbmUuZXhh
bXBsZT4KClRoaXMgaXMgYSBtZXNzYWdlIGp1c3QgdG8gc2F5IGhlbGxvLiBTbywgIkhlbGxvIi4=
```

Now pass this in the `raw` parameter of the API Explorer.

Comment: url encoding required. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128789/converting-string-to-web-safe-base64-format

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AkashkumarDev/20ab002e7f5785ae778e
any idea where is problem ?

Comment: @akdev for questions please start a new question instead of commenting here. thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396463/how-to-send-message-using-gmail-api-with-ruby-google-api-client

Comment: Doesn't work for me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122074/gmail-api-emails-bouncing

Comment: @taifun, my message sending successfully. but, how to add threadId and labelId while sending the message?

Comment: @users4393829 please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: already did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960683/gmail-api-adding-label-id-and-thread-id-while-sending-as-reply-send-mail-with-s

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me**

Url: `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send`  (POST Method)

InHeaders:-
"`Authorization` " :  "`Bearer ya29.Il-iBylW9AUr6V0QO72ryo17r7hf8i5zh8dU63ZjDNaxAApumh6T7lh20my_DQZomtL_qokZnJEgapYN20LmdlG6lFbqGASL5lqFAKnOoUtZA992JwOlUQxMVW6_Yto7jQ`",
"`Content-Type`" : "`message/rfc822`"

InBody:-

```
{"raw": "From: <from@gmail.com> 
To: <to@gmail.com> 
Subject: Saying Hello
This is a message just to say hello. So, "Hello"."}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is a PHP specific answer, but I'm sure some of you will find it useful.

In case you're struggling with setting up the raw data correctly in PHP as I did, using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) would make things cleaner and easier for you.

After including the library in your code (if you use composer, just add "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2" in the require section of your composer.json), you set the basic details:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'FROM_EMAIL';
$mail->FromName = 'FROM_NAME';
$mail->addAddress('TO_EMAIL','TO_NAME');
$mail->Subject = 'EMAIL_SUBJECT';
$mail->Body = 'EMAIL_BODY';
$mail->preSend(); 
$mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
```

Now you can base64 encode the $mime to get the raw string for the Gmail API. Use this instead of simple base64_encode, in order to get a valid web safe encoded string.
`rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($mime), '+/', '-_'), '=');`

Comment: the question is : "using the new Gmail REST API?"... so why talk about PHPMailer...

Comment: @mcfly because I spent two days researching how to implement this in PHP and I figured why not share my findings on this lovely knowledge sharing platform, with people who, like me, ran onto this answer because they couldn't find what they're looking for.
Note the disclaimer at the top.
Happy Monday!

Comment: still not in the right subject... i can post how to send and email with python then java too and people looking for the real subject answer will be so happy to find this here.

Comment: This does answer the question in a sense that you get a fully prepared message built by PHPMailer and then use Gmail API to send it. The idea is to get some 3rd party library and not deal with the raw settings of the message.

Answer (score 1):

you could also send it as a messsage.
e.g.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send


Headers:-
"Authorization":"Bearer <Your-Token>", 
"Content-Type" : "message/rfc822"

Body:
"From: <from@gmail.com> 
To: <to@gmail.com> 
Subject: Saying Hello
This is a message just to say hello. So, 'Hello'"
```

Comment: In fact, this is correct answer. The answer by Taifun that is currently of the highest score is verbose, not to the point, and is inferior to this answer. This shows the problem of the legacy scoring system of SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me...

Instead of manually creating the email message and encoding it entirely as base64, we need to follow the RFC 2822 format for email messages and then encode specific parts.

So, I encoded only the message body as base64 (and left the headers in clear text).

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

function encode(str, urlSafe = false) {
    const encoded = Buffer.from(str).toString('base64');
    return urlSafe ? encoded.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_') : encoded;
}

function createEmail(sender, receiver, subject, message) {
    const emailLines = [];
    emailLines.push(`From: ${sender}`);
    emailLines.push(`To: ${receiver}`);
    emailLines.push(`Subject: ${subject}`);
    emailLines.push('');
    emailLines.push(message); // Message body

    const email = emailLines.join('\r\n');
    const encodedEmail = encode(email);

    return encodedEmail;
}

export default async function sendEmailWithGmailAPI({ sender, receiver, subject, message }, { auth }) {
    const { access_token } = await auth.getToken();
    if (!receiver || !receiver.includes('@')) {
        throw new Error('Invalid receiver email address');
    }

    const rawMessage = createEmail(sender, receiver, subject, message);

    const response = await fetch(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            raw: rawMessage,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```