# Sending gmail attachment using api failed

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, attachment, gmail-api

I'm trying create a draft (or send a message) with attachment to gmail using its API. I've read some answers and tried to built the request according to what I've read here: [Mail attachment wrong media type Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908700/mail-attachment-wrong-media-type-gmail-api)

Before coding the function itself, I decided to use a Chrome extension (Simple Rest Client) to simulate the API request. Here's the request body:

```
Content-Type: multipart_mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
MIME-Version: 1.0
to: receiver@gmail.com
from: sender@gmail.com
subject: Testing Subject

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is the testing text

--foo_bar_baz

Content-Type: image/jpeg
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.jpg"

{
"message":
{
"raw" :     "_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD_2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz_2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz_wAARCAAJAAsDASIAAhEBAxEB_8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL_8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4-Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3-Pn6_8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL_8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3-Pn6_9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9Pfiv-wN4q8cftk3Pji30_wCH9z9v8V6H4ksPiFe3cy-MvAunaeuni68N6bCLR92n3_2G8ErLf2yAeIL_AHW021xdfX9FFAH_2Q**"
}
}

--foo_bar_baz--
```

The request header parameters are as follows:

```
Authorization: Bearer *given token*
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
Content-Length: 1428
```

As you can see, it's pretty similar to the example in the link above. However, I keep getting the following response:

```
"message": "Media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822]"
```

I know the API docs say the only valid media type is message/rfc822 (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create). Nonetheless, this sample (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#multipart) and others here in Stackoverflow say otherwise. The author of the question in the link above seem to have solved his problem without using message/rfc822 media type.

I gotta be missing something. Can someone help me with this? I'd really appreciate if someone could help me figure it out.

Comment: Hi Geppetto. Could you please share your final POST-format of when you got it to work? Struggling with this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so if you're using the /upload media feature (works for all messages irregardless of size)  then for example it should be something like the following (and looks like i was a bit mistaken):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
```

then your POST body should be something like the following (not encoded, etc):

```
--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: message/rfc822
MIME-Version: 1.0
to: receiver@gmail.com
from: sender@gmail.com
subject: Testing Subject

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is the testing text

--foo_bar_baz

Content-Type: image/jpeg
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.jpg"




--foo_bar_baz--
```

So things to note are that it's actually "multipart/related" and that has a application/json (for some requests you can add parameters there) part as well as a message/rfc822 part that contains the entire email.

It's not easy for sure--libraries definitely make it less painful if you can use them!

Comment: Hi, @EricDeFriez. Thanks for the answer. I'm posting directly to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?uploadType=multipart. So, should I include both the message and the attachment in the _raw_ parameter? How do I do this? Where do I include the filename, for example?

Comment: Got it! I was surely mixing up lots of different stuff. Cooled down, read a bit and figured it out. Your tip of setting "Content-Type: message/rfc822" on the POST header was crucial. I haven't read it anywhere but here. Thanks a lot. I'll soon post my final HTTP POST format, so others can benefit of it too. Again, thanks, your answer was very time saving.

Comment: @Geppetto, although it is 3 years later, I eagerly await your final HTTP POST format comment.  The documentation hasn't gotten much better since you were working this. If you have it around, I'd love to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Use the message structure that [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908700/mail-attachment-wrong-media-type-gmail-api), set the Content-Type header to message/rfc822, and most importantly send the message as is in the body, no base64 encoding. This worked for me with the uploadtype header set to media.  I hope you see this @Bryan