# Sending Gmail attachments always "bounce" back

Tags: gmail, google-chrome-app, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail REST API on a Chrome App, I have succeed sent mail without attachments, but when I was trying to send with attachments, it always failed and I got an email named "Bounce" from nobody@gmail.com, it said "An error occurred. Your message was not sent.", no more detail.

My code are copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24957873/2710304), to test if I made something wrong, I changed these code to "draft" version, I successfully created a draft with attachment, even more I send the draft from Gmail web succeed. but when I send mail or send my created draft from app, it always failed.

Here is my email's "Show original" from Gmail web which I sent from app:

```
Received: from 720314066041-rqjqsu7v5apq2s2n05sa63o9s7fed56g.apps.googleusercontent.com
    named unknown
    by gmailapi.google.com
    with HTTPREST;
    Fri, 26 Dec 2014 22:18:06 -0800
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-------314159265358979323846"
From: AAA@gmail.com
To: BBB@sina.com
Subject: Welcome
---------314159265358979323846
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Date: Fri, 26 Dec 2014 22:18:06 -0800
Message-Id: <CAP5pmxTve5ToN=f0LjVFZ9YwvQDAiZhKcWUa1rjqxz91EWH6Uw@mail.gmail.com>

This is my first email.   
---------314159265358979323846
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;name="abc.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.txt"

1234567
---------314159265358979323846-
```

Has anyone succeed to send attachments from app these days? or has Google forbidden to send attachments from app with REST API? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it's my fault :). It seems a blank new line is required immediately before `delimiter("-------314159265358979323846")`, now everything works prefect.