# How to insert message with Content-Type message/rfc2822 using Gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api, google-schemas

I wanna write a small application that copy Gmail messages from one user folder to another. My approach is next:

1. Get raw message data to temporary placeholder;
2. Compose message using raw message data from the previous step;
3. Add message to required folder.

I can get raw message data as RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string using [this get request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

Also I can insert message to user mailbox with [insert request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert). As documentation states, I can use one of the next two approaches:

1. use **/upload** URL (then I need an uploadType string and I should have a content-type of message/rfc822);
2. not using **/upload** URL and simply set message metadata in the request body -
   something like the next JSON:

   ```
   {
    "labelIds": [
      "INBOX",
      "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS"
     ],
     "raw": "UmVjZWl2ZWQ6IGZyb20gMjkyODI0MTMyMDgyDQoJ..."
   }
   ```

Unfortunately, when I don't use **/upload** URL (approach (2)) I can't insert message with attachment bigger than 5MB. But if I use **/upload** URL (approach (1)) I get response with error

> "Media type 'message/rfc2822' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822]".

How can I support insertion of messages to Gmail without restriction on messages attachment size?

Comment: You don't need to encode the mail into a `raw` string if you are using the `/upload` endpoint. Maybe the [**edit at the bottom of this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908700/mail-attachment-wrong-media-type-gmail-api/24957873#24957873) can give some clues?

Comment: I think the problem I described above is clear: I can ether use **/upload** URL and don't set "raw" or don't use **/upload** URL and set "raw" data field in as RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string.