# how to send message using Gmail API with Ruby Google API Client?

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail-api

i'm facing several problem with API,

first:

send method asking for 'id'(message id or thread id) .. but why ?
   i'm sending new message so it shouldn't require . according to Gmail Api documnetation
   its optional .
   https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

```
ArgumentError: Missing required parameters: id.
```

second:

even after specify message id it return this message .

```
 Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
```

code

```
 require 'mime'
 include MIME



msg = Mail.new
msg.date = Time.now
msg.subject = 'This is important'
msg.headers.set('Priority', 'urgent')

msg.body = Text.new('hello, world!', 'plain', 'charset' => 'us-ascii')
msg.from = {'hi@gmail.com' => 'Boss Man'}
msg.to   = {
    'list@example.com' => nil,
    'john@example.com' => 'John Doe',
    'jane@example.com' => 'Jane Doe',
}

@email = @google_api_client.execute(
    api_method: @gmail.users.messages.send(:get),
    body_object: {
        raw: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(msg.to_s)
    },
    parameters: {
        userId: 'me'
    }
)
```

and of-course authentication working fine.

some other methods also working fine

like:

```
get list of messages(Users.messages.list)

get single message(Users.messages.get)
```

but

send message not working .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>I think</strike>

```
@gmail.users.messages.send(:get) is equal to @gmail.users.messages.get
```

because ".send" is ruby method

so now this method is working with

```
@gmail.users.messages.to_h['gmail.users.messages.send']
```

example:

```
msg = Mail.new
msg.date = Time.now
msg.subject = options[:subject]
msg.body = Text.new(options[:message])
msg.from = {@_user.email => @_user.full_name}
msg.to   = {
    options[:to] => options[:to_name]
}
@email = @google_api_client.execute(
    api_method: @gmail.users.messages.to_h['gmail.users.messages.send'],
    body_object: {
        raw: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(msg.to_s)
    },
    parameters: {
        userId: 'me',
    }
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: My Gist https://gist.github.com/joselo/8e7464df88344c69a42b

Any idea of this error? 

DATA:{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"invalidArgument", "message"=>"Invalid to header"}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Invalid to header"}}

Comment: From what is @gmail initialised?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have a look at this gem I just built that use Gmail API and not using IMAP and SMTP like other gems:

```
gem install gmail-api-ruby
m = Gmail::Message.new(to: test@test.com, subject: "hello", html: "<b>this is html part<b>, text: "this is the text part")
m.deliver
```

[gmail-api-ruby](https://github.com/jhk753/gmail-ruby-api)

It comes with a lot of helpful methods that you use in Gmail interface