# Creating a Message with Attachement GmailV1 API ruby

Tags: ruby, api, gmail-api, google-api-client

I am trying to send a en email with an attachment via the `GmailV1` API. However it just isn't working due to `Missing Draft Message` errors.

According to [RubyDoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService) I tried to create a draft message as follows:

The `GmailV1:GmailService.create_user_draft()` methods takes in an identifier and a `draft_object` (accepting `'me'` for the authorized user). A draft object (`Google::Apis::GmailV1::Draft`) takes a `message` in the form of `Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message` which in turn takes a `payload` in the form of `Google::Apis::GmailV1::MessagePart` which has the desired `filename` method.

So I ran this code:

```
##assume client is an authorized instance of Google::Apis::GmailV1:GmailService
msg_part = Google::Apis::GmailV1::MessagePart.new(filename: 'path/to/file')
msg = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(payload: msg_part)
draft = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Draft.new(message: msg)
client.create_user_draft('me', draft)

>> Google::Apis::ClientError: invalidArgument: Missing draft message
```

How Come?

Versions:

- google-api-client 0.9.9
- googleauth 0.5.1
- ruby 2.3.1p112

Comment: Have you stumbled upon [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396463/how-to-send-message-using-gmail-api-with-ruby-google-api-client)? Might give some clues.

Comment: I have but it refers to an old version of the API that is completely different now in every way, from authentication to making API requests. It doesn't apply / help here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `GmailService` class as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby) I was able to save a draft using the code below. I think the key is that the `raw` keyword is required in the message.

```
result = service.create_user_draft(
  user_id,
  Google::Apis::GmailV1::Draft.new(
    :message => Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(
      :raw => "To: test@test.com\r\nSubject: Test Message\r\n\r\nTest Body"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem creating first a Mail object with the 'mail' gem in this way:

```
require 'mail'

mail = Mail.new
mail['from'] = 'pippo@pluto.it'
mail[:to]    = 'me@mymail.it'
mail.subject = 'This is a test email'
mail.body 'this is the body'
mail.add_file("./path/to/file")
#... and other ...
```

then i converted this in a raw object:

```
raw_message = mail.to_s
```

then i create gmail message with this raw:

```
message = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(
  :raw => raw_message  
)
```

and finnaly:

```
draft = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Draft.new(message: message)
gmail.create_user_draft('me', draft)
```