# How to send an email using the Google API Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api-client

I am new to Ruby and using the Google API. I am trying to send an email using the following code:

```
msg = Mail.new
msg.date = Time.now
msg.subject = 'Testing'
msg.body = '<p>Hi Alex, hows life?</p>'
msg.from = self.email
msg.to   = 'fakeemail@gmail.com'

@email = @google_api_client.execute(
    api_method: @gmail.users.messages.to_h['gmail.users.messages.send'],
    body_object: {
        raw: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(msg.to_s)
    },
    parameters: {
        userId: 'me',
    }
)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant Mail (NameError)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please cross verify whether you installed a `mail gem` of not

Comment: I don't have the mail gem I think. Will writing "gem 'mail'" in my gem file and then running a bundle install fix this?

Comment: yes, it should fix your problem

Comment: Just tried it and got the same exact error.

Comment: can you please have a look at, https://github.com/mikel/mail, it might help you

Comment: I have looked at that, but I am trying to use Google's official API, not this.

Comment: okay, I found one answer here please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396463/how-to-send-message-using-gmail-api-with-ruby-google-api-client

Comment: My question is based off that question. I have similar code to the guy who answered the question, however mine is not working, and I do not know why.

Comment: @Shurick ruby won't auto load gems for you, try to manually load the mail gem by add `require 'mail'` at the top of the file.

Comment: That helped thanks.