# Google REST API - message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string

Tags: api, rest, gmail-api

I try the use the - [try it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it) of [Google REST API - Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) .

There is there a required parameter - `raw` -

> *The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string. Returned in messages.get and drafts.get responses when
>   the format=RAW parameter is supplied.*

I checked about RFC 2822 format and seems it should displayed as the [sample here](http://www.boogietools.com/Products/Linux/BounceStudioAPI/help/files/RawMessageFormat.html) , then I encoded it the base64URL with this encoder and paste it the `raw` field of the [try it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it) and I get  - `Invalid value for ByteString: http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html` .

Can you provide me a correct `RFC 2822 format` and its corresponding `base64URL` which it would work in the above [try it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it) ?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460422/how-to-send-a-message-successfully-using-the-new-gmail-rest-api which has all information about RFC 2822 specification

Comment: [example using node and formatted json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441660/gmail-rest-api-json-to-send-message/70909067#70909067)

Comment: Indeed, Google API is not just Base64, as it contains the following characters "-_" as detected with https://base64.guru/tools/validator

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An example mail could look like this:

```
From: sender@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Subject: Subject Text

The message text goes here
```

Open up the Developer Tools in your browser and Base64 encode it and replace all `+` with `-`, replace all `/` with `_`, and remove the trailing `=` to make it URL-safe:

```
btoa(
  "From: sender@gmail.com\r\n" +
  "To: receiver@gmail.com\r\n" +
  "Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n" +

  "The message text goes here"
).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
```

This will give you the following data:

`RnJvbTogc2VuZGVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ0KVG86IHJlY2VpdmVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ0KU3ViamVjdDogU3ViamVjdCBUZXh0DQoNClRoZSBtZXNzYWdlIHRleHQgZ29lcyBoZXJl`

Use this string above as your `raw`-parameter in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it) to send the mail.

Comment: Can anyone share any link or res, on how to decode the above encoded data, back to original message string.?

Comment: @RohitNandi You can try the [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in node REPL or online node compiler and get the json

```
function createMessageJson(){
    const messages = [
        'From: NAME <foo@email.com>',
        'To: Name <foobar@email.com>',
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Subject: Re: SUBJECT',
        '',
        'BODY_TEXT',
        '',
    ];


    function encodedMessage (){
        return Buffer.from(messages.join('\n'))
            .toString('base64')
            .replace(/\+/g, '-')
            .replace(/\//g, '_')
            .replace(/=+$/, '');
    }


  return JSON.stringify({
            raw: encodedMessage()
    });
}

console.log(createMessageJson())
```