# Send email via Gmail API (Javascript)

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to get a hello world sending a mail via the JS Gmail API.  I have authorised correctly (labels can be listed) according to [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js).

I'm using the following code, running in the browser:

```js
const message =
"From: my.email@gmail.com\r\n" + 
"To: my.email@gmail.com\r\n" +
"Subject: As basic as it gets\r\n\r\n" +
"This is the plain text body of the message.  Note the blank line between the header information and the body of the message.";


// The body needs to be base64url encoded.
const encodedMessage = btoa(message)

const reallyEncodedMessage = encodedMessage.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '')

gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: 'me',
    requestBody: {
        // same response with any of these
        raw: reallyEncodedMessage
        // raw: encodedMessage
        // raw: message
    }
}).then(function () { console.log("done!")});
```

This gives an HTTP 400 response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"
 }
}
```

This is using JS API available at `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js`.  RFC822 example taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527253(v=exchg.10).aspx) and [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133630/614523).  Web-safe base64 encoding the RFC822 message as far as I can tell is a the standard with this API.  Same error in both Firefox and Chrome.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you could share your github project please? all code ?

Comment: @jonathasborges1 long since deleted sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the raw data is correct. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
requestBody: {
    // same response with any of these
    raw: reallyEncodedMessage
    // raw: encodedMessage
    // raw: message
}
```

#### To :

```
resource: { // Modified
    // same response with any of these
    raw: reallyEncodedMessage
    // raw: encodedMessage
    // raw: message
}
```

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to think of other solution.

Comment: @sennett I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: please could share where you found documentation about lib "gapi" to answer this ask?

Comment: @jonathasborges1 About your question of `please could share where you found documentation about lib "gapi" to answer this ask?`, how about this? https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to code work but code work by removing the body that are been added to you raw statement.

```
gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
            userId: 'me',
                // resourse: {
                // same response with any of these
                raw: reallyEncodedMessage
                // raw: encodedMessage
                // raw: message
            // }
```

I hope you try this because answer by @Tanaike was not working for me

Comment: sorry , as it is not organised