# gmail API send email error:Recipient address required

Tags: api, email, gmail, send

Gmail API send email `error:Recipient address required`

[image]

Comment: You need to encode the message into the raw field
[code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441660/gmail-rest-api-json-to-send-message/70909067#70909067)

Answer (score 0):

I searched over many articles and realized that **ALL CONTENTS RELATED TO THE EMAIL SHOULD BE ENCODED IN RAW**, including recipient email and body.

Please refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25494682/18200202) by [Eric D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3758997/eric-d)

Trying to use the payload parameters was in vain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).