# How to send mail using gmail rest api from postmnan native application

Tags: postman, gmail-api

My requirement is that send an email to some recipient with text body using POSTMAN Native app,
I used the below endpoint with requested data,

1. Base URL: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send
2. Headers :`Authorization:Bearer`
3. Request Method :`POST`
4. Request body :`{"raw";"to:user1mail@gmail.com","subject":"Test_Mail"}`
5. Clicking Send button

But getting error response code 400,required recipient address
Please help me in this to send an email using POSTMAN,and I've tried with upload end point too -https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/user1email@gmail.com/messages/send

Thanks in advance,looking for help guys

Comment: Tried this one also, but no luck, guys it would be great, for help in this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460422/how-to-send-a-message-successfully-using-the-new-gmail-rest-api
I want to send mail with raw text with Gmail Rest API using postman

Comment: Please refer [https://stackoverflow.com/q/58909602/11602270](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58909602/11602270) It has a detailed description of it.

Answer (score 1):

Came across your question trying to figure this out myself today.

> 4. Request body : `{"raw";"to:user1mail@gmail.com","subject":"Test_Mail"}`

The `raw` param should be a complete email message that's base64-encoded.

i.e.:  `{"raw": "VG86IHVzZXIxbWFpbEBnbWFpbC5jb20KU3ViamVjdDogVGVzdF9NYWls"}`

Answer (score 0):

400 error means bad request, which could mean there are missing or wrong parameters. Check the [Users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

> **Path parameters**
>
> userId  string  The user's email address. The special value me can be
>   used to indicate the authenticated user.
>
> Required query parameters
>
> uploadType  string  The type of upload request to the /upload URI.
>   Acceptable values are:
>
> **media** - Simple upload. Upload the media only, without any metadata.
>
> **multipart** - Multipart upload. Upload both the media and its metadata, in a single request.
>
> **resumable** - Resumable upload. Upload the file in a resumable fashion, using a series of at least two requests where the first
>   request includes the metadata.