# 400 error. Recipient address required. JavaScript

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I make a simple request step-by-step in Gmail API.

According to all instructions I made this call:

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    'userId': 'me',
    "payload": {
    "headers": [
             {
              "name": "To",
              "value": "########@gmail.com"
             }
           ]},
     'raw': 'SEVMTE8gTVkgREVBUiBGUklFTkQ='
     });

request.then(()=>{console.log('yep')})
```

But receive an error:

```
{
   "error": {
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "invalidArgument",
       "message": "Recipient address required"
     }
   ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Recipient address required"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct format in sending to emails in Gmail API is stated in [Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send):

```
function sendMessage(userId, email, callback) {
  // Using the js-base64 library for encoding:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64
  var base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email);
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    'userId': userId,
    'resource': {
      'raw': base64EncodedEmail
    }
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

For a more vivid sample on how to use this method, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460422/how-to-send-a-message-successfully-using-the-new-gmail-rest-api):

> [...] the complete message needs to be passed in the `raw` parameter, see the example:
>
> ```
> From: John Doe <jdoe@machine.example> 
> To: Mary Smith <mary@example.net> 
> Subject: Saying Hello 
> Date: Fri, 21 Nov 1997 09:55:06 -0600 
> Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>
>
> This is a message just to say hello. So, "Hello".
> ```
>
> So after base64 encoding the complete message, passing it in the `raw` parameter without using any other parameter, it works fine.

Comment: Encoding whole info into base64 hellped to solve sending issue. Thank you a lot.
Can you help me  either to send an html letter?

Comment: I've figured out how to send an html letter. To add a *Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8* became a resolution. 
Thank you once again/