# Testing Send endpoint for Gmail API with Postman

Tags: javascript, ajax, gmail, postman, gmail-api

I am trying to send emails with the Gmail API. I am trying to use Postman to test my requests and get the proper code to use in my web application, but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalidArgument",
            "message": "Recipient address required"
        }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Recipient address required"
   }
}
```

I'm using the following link to make a POST request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send
```

In my header, I have the following:

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.xxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: message/rfc822
```

In my request body:

```
{

"raw" : "RnJvbTogQWxleCBCdWhzZSA8YWxleGJ1aHNlMUBnbWFpbC5jb20-IApUbzogQWxleCBCdWhzZSA8a29vX29saW9AaG90bWFpbC5jb20-IApTdWJqZWN0OiBTYXlpbmcgSGVsbG8geW8KRGF0ZTogRnJpLCAyMSBOb3YgMTk5NyAwOTo1NTowNiAtMDYwMApDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IHRleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOA=="

}
```

I have tested the request with through the API testing sidebar on Google's own documentation:

```
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
```

but I seem to not be having any luck with using it in Postman. I'm using Postman and not the javascript that Google provides because I want to get the proper formatted code for making an AJAX call. I was wondering if anyone has worked with Postman and the Gmail API that may be able to help?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out where I was going wrong. I changed content-type to:

```
Content-Type: application/JSON
```

And I changed the request link to:

```
 https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send
```

And that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Host: www.googleapis.com

Content-Type: message/rfc822

Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 3b313d0c-e678-49cd-b977-017b6380a25f

 {
  "raw": "ZnJvbTpteUBnbWFpbC5jb20KdG86c29tZW9uZUByb2JvbXEuaW8KY2M6eW91QGdtYWlsLmNvbQpzdWJqZWN0OlRlc3QgRnJvbSBQb3N0bWFuCk1lc3NhZ2UtSWQ6IGNoZWNraW5nIGluIHBvc3RtYW4KSGVsbG8gRnJvbSBQb3N0bWFuIGluc2h1"
,

  "id": "me" ,


  payload": {

    "filename": "Filename",

    "mimeType": "message/rfc822",

    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "to",

        "value": "me"
      },
    ],

  "body": 
{
      "attachmentId": "/home/inshu/Desktop/signup.txt",

      "data": "",

      "size": 1524
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you want more details please refer below link:

[400 error. Recipient address required. JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138836/400-error-recipient-address-required-javascript)