# How to use Gmail API without raw attribute in JSON

Tags: google-api, gmail, sendmail, gmail-api

I'm try to send email using google gmail API. I've used Request body JSON with bearer token and Content-Type - message/rfc822.

Then I've used link below to send post request but I received the following errors.how to fix this issue ???

Post request Link -
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/kasunysoft@gmail.com/messages/send

Request Body

```
  {
               "threadId": "Hi kasunjith",
               "payload": {
                "mimeType": "message/rfc822",
                "headers": [
                  {
                    "name": "To",
                    "value": "hvn@gmail.com"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "From",
                    "value":"kasunysoft@gmail.com"
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"Subject",
                    "value":"Subject Text"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
```

I got response

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalidArgument",
                "message": "Recipient address required"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Recipient address required"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your format in sending email is not valid. Check the documentation for [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) and [Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) for the proper format.

> ```
> {
>   "id": string,
>   "threadId": string,
>   "labelIds": [
>     string
>   ],
>   "snippet": string,
>   "historyId": unsigned long,
>   "internalDate": long,
>   "payload": {
>     "partId": string,
>     "mimeType": string,
>     "filename": string,
>     "headers": [
>       {
>         "name": string,
>         "value": string
>       }
>     ],
>     "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
>     "parts": [
>       (MessagePart)
>     ]
>   },
>   "sizeEstimate": integer,
>   "raw": bytes
> }
> ```

You can also check out the following SO post for more in depth discussion about you error.

- [400 error. Recipient address required. JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138836/400-error-recipient-address-required-javascript)
- [How to send a message successfully using the new Gmail REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460422/how-to-send-a-message-successfully-using-the-new-gmail-rest-api)

Comment: Is it compulsorily to use raw attribute in JSON and how to add sender ,receiver mail address and message