# Get messages in users' GMail inbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail-api

In the code below I am signing in, authorising the app, and getting console output via the GMail API. I believe I am getting the threads and thread IDs, but I am not seeing the messages in the console.

I am not getting any errors and I am getting output, just what seems like keys with no values.

Here is what the console output looks like: [image]

Here is the code:

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
var USER = 'me';

  /**
   * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
  }

  /**
   * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
        handleAuthResult);
  }

  /**
   * Called when authorization server replies.
   *
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
    var outputNotice = document.getElementById('notice');
    authButton.style.display = 'none';
    outputNotice.style.display = 'block';
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
      gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
        listThreads(USER, function(resp) {
          var threads = resp.threads;
          for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            var thread = threads[i];
            console.log(thread);
            console.log(thread['id']);
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
      authButton.style.display = 'block';
      outputNotice.style.display = 'none';
      authButton.onclick = function() {
          gapi.auth.authorize(
              {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': false},
              handleAuthResult);
      };
    }
  }


  /**
   * Get a page of Threads.
   *
   * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
   * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * @param  {Function} callback Function called when request is complete.
   */
  function listThreads(userId, callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.threads.list({
      'userId': userId
    });
    request.execute(callback);
  }
```

**How can I retrieve the from address, subject, and body of the messages? with the GMAIL API in js**

**Update: What I am currently working with: **

```
listThreads('me', function(dataResult){
    $.each(dataResult, function(i, item){
        getThread('me', item.id, function(dataMessage){
            console.log(dataMessage);
            var temp = dataMessage.messages[0].payload.headers;
            $.each(temp, function(j, dataItem){
                if(dataItem.name == 'From'){
                    console.log(dataItem.value);
                }
            });
         });
      });
   });
```

When I log dataMessage, I get a 400 error, ' id required '.
When I log dataItem.value, I get a dataMessage.messages is undefined and can not have an index of 0.

I'd greatly appreciate help in getting this working!

Answer (score 1):

GMail api in Javascript does not explicit methods to access particular email part - to/from/etc. GMail api in Java has this feature.
Gmail api in Javascript are still in Beta. [api list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads)

You still wanna do it: Here is outline:

Instead of getting list of threads get list of messages:
[message list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)

Parse message id from json retrieved from previous call, use it with following:
[message get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

Get raw message in URL encoded base64 format.
Decode and parse.
[safe encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128789/converting-string-to-web-safe-base64-format)
[encoding](http://www.base64encode.org/)

Difficult... You bet... :)

Comment: can you show me how to get the threads list? With what I am currently doing, I get the id in the console. But how do I get the messages from there? Here is a live example: irfanknow.com/gmail.html

Answer (score 1):

**Here's what i did to get the *from email id* from message**

After calling the `listThread()` method, i called `getThread()` method to fetch the from email ID from that thread as following.

```
listThreads("me", "", function (dataResult) {
         $.each(dataResult, function (i, item) {
           getThread("me", item.id, function (dataMessage) {
             var temp = dataMessage.messages[0].payload.headers;
             $.each(temp, function (j, dataItem) {
                   if (dataItem.name == "From") {
                       Console.log(dataItem.value);
                    }
             });
        });
    });
});
```

Similarly you can fetch other details from the message.

**Reference** : [JSON Format for the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource)

Comment: What does your entire code look like? I am trying what you have above and am still getting nothing in the console. Here is what all my code looks like: https://gist.github.com/theirf/f142d3b02e5e2343403a What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I ran it and was getting an error that `string is not a function`, but then I removed the second argument from listThreads and I got no errors. Except now, I am again getting nothing in console. No errors or results. Here is what I have: https://gist.github.com/theirf/71464ac6e9ead6425074

Comment: @user3743069 debug your code using F12 in chrome or FireFox, check if you are getting proper response or not...

Comment: @user3743069 have you added the getThreads() method, if not then check `gist.github.com/theirf/71464ac6e9ead6425074`, i have added the method there

Comment: Thank you. Now, I am using your getThread() function, but am getting an error. it says `.messages` is undefined? and there is no index 0 of .messages since it is undefined. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/theirf/71464ac6e9ead6425074

Comment: @user3743069 check if you are getting anything in `dataResult` or is it also `undefined`???

Comment: I am getting a 400 error saying that the id is required. I have put my code and the errors at the bottom of my question. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Like Amit says above you can use messages.list() to get a list of message ids.  With those you can simply call messages.get() and that will return an email in *parsed* form and you can get to the headers via message.payload.headers.  You don't need to get the 'raw' message base64 encoded.