# AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get returns photoData object instead of string - how to encode/show on webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

In Google Apps Script, I am using the AdminDirectory Api to get a user photo from the admin console.

The returned object shoud have a string containing the photo encoded as base64, but I can only get an object of numbers.

```
function hentSkolefoto() {
  var photo = AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get("bend0006@thistedskoler.dk");
  Logger.log(typeof(photo.photoData));
  Logger.log(photo.photoData.toString());
}
```

The log output says:

```
object
Logging output too large. Truncating output. [-1.0, -40.0, -1.0, -32.0, 0.0, 16.0,...
```

How do I decode and - ultimately - show the photo on a web page?

I have tried to add "toString()":

```
Logger.log(photo.photoData.toString())
```

Log output:

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. -1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,...
```

I have also tried to decode as suggested [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126152/retrieve-and-display-image-from-base64-from-google-admin-sdk?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It seems that from `How do I decode and - ultimately - show the photo on a web page?`, in your question, there are 2 questions. I can answer to your 1st question of `How do I decode`. But, unfortunately, I cannot answer to your 2nd question of `show the photo on a web page?`. Because I cannot know the specification of your web pages. I apologize for this. In this case, how should I do this?

Comment: What I would like to end up with is a string, I can put in here: `document.getElementById("img").src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+photodata;`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your expected goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of AdminDirectory at Advanced Google services, it seems that `AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get("###").photoData` returns the byte array of int8array. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function hentSkolefoto() {
  var photo = AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get("bend0006@thistedskoler.dk");
  Logger.log(typeof(photo.photoData));
  Logger.log(photo.photoData.toString());
}
```

#### To:

From your reply of `What I would like to end up with is a string, I can put in here:' document .getElementById("img") .src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+photodata;'`, when the value of `photo.photoData` is converted to the data URL, how about the following modification?

```
function hentSkolefoto() {
  var photo = AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get("bend0006@thistedskoler.dk");
  var byteArray = photo.photoData;
  var dataUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(byteArray)}`; // When the mimeType of photo is PNG.
  console.log(dataUrl); // You can see the value at the console.

  // do something.

}
```

If you want to create the data as a file, you can also use the following sample script.

```
function hentSkolefoto() {
  var photo = AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get("bend0006@thistedskoler.dk");
  var byteArray = photo.photoData;
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(byteArray); // or Utilities.newBlob(byteArray, "mimeType", "filename")
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

- By this modification, the byte array is converted to the data URL.

#### Reference:

- [base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata)

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Benno_fra_DK Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. With your cooperation, I could understand your question. Thank you, too.